# Connecting to Urban Airship REST API with c#

Tags: c#, api, rest, httprequest, urbanairship.com

I am getting a 400 bad request error when trying to connect to the Urban Airship Rest API. Below is the curl command I am trying to replicate in .NET. The .NET code is at the end. Please help.

> ```
> curl -v -X POST 
> -u "username:passowrd" 
> -H "Content-type: application/json" 
> -H "Accept: application/vnd.urbanairship+json; version=3;" 
> --data '{"audience" : {"tag":"1_13_98"},                  
>        "device_types" : "all",                    
>        "notification" : {"alert": "Tag push alert"}       
>   }' 
>   https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push
> ```

The c# code I am trying to use is:

```
    var json = gcm.ToJsonString();
    Console.WriteLine("JSON GCM Message: " + json);
    var uri = new Uri("https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/?");
    var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, master);
    request.ContentType = "application/json";

    WebHeaderCollection myWebHeaderCollection = request.Headers;
    myWebHeaderCollection.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/vnd.urbanairship+json; version=3;");

    request.ContentLength = encoding.GetByteCount(json);

    using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(encoding.GetBytes(json), 0, encoding.GetByteCount(json));
        stream.Close();
        var response = request.GetResponse();
        response.Close();
    }

    return true;
```

The API for urbanAirship can be found here:
http://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/api/v3/push.html

And here is an example request..

```
POST /api/push HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic <master authorization string>
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/vnd.urbanairship+json; version=3;
{
  "audience" : {
      "device_token" : "998BAD77A8347EFE7920F5367A4811C4385D526AE42C598A629A73B94EEDBAC8"
  },
  "notification" : {
       "alert" : "Hello!"
  },
  "device_types" : "all"
}
```

Comment: The exception gets thrown in the following line:  theWebHeaderCollection myWebHeaderCollection = request.Headers;
    myWebHeaderCollection.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/vnd.urbanairship+json; version=3;");

Comment: If I remove the line, the 400 Bad Request is returned.

Comment: What exception gets thrown when trying to add to the header collection?

Comment: The following exception: The 'Accept' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.
Parameter name: name

Comment: Have you tried setting the value using: request.Accept = "application/vnd.urbanairship+json; version=3;"

Comment: Yes, thats what I first tried, then found a couple of stack overflow answers which said to do this.

Comment: If you use the request.Accept property, do you still get a 400? If so have you looked in the response body for more details? See: https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/60923-troubleshooting-http-status-codes

Comment: Hey Dan, I must have been mistaken, I just tried  request.Accept = "application/vnd.urbanairship+json; version=3;"  and it work. I think I tried something like request.Headers.Accept or something.. anyways that's great! thanks for your help.. if you add the answer below.. I'll mark it as the answer :)

Comment: Glad it worked :) I've added an answer which I think will be useful to anyone who comes across this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the header collection (which is throwing an exception) try setting the Accept property on the Request object, e.g. request.Accept = "application/vnd.urbanairship+json; version=3;"

If you still get a 400, try looking in the response body for more details.

Answer (score 3):

I've created a c# .Net library for talking to Urban Airship API V3

You can find it here:

https://github.com/JeffGos/urbanairsharp

Hope it helps

Comment: Are you planning to work on this library? I see that the latest checkin was 2 years ago...

Comment: It currently handle's all the basic use cases of Urban Airship API 2.0. I don't have time to maintain this library, but you are welcome to contribute to it.

Comment: unfortunately not the RichMessage which I need. But I have already forked and adapt it to my needs.

Comment: ok great - you can submit a Pull Request if you'd like your changes to be integrated into the project